# Can I set a programmatically set a property of any type?

Tags: kotlin, reflection, properties

I'm trying to write a function that sets a property in a data class given a property type and a value. The data class has properties of several types, like String, View and Int, and some properties are nullable. I can make this work if I limit the functionality to one type, like this:

```
fun setDataValue(index: TableIndex, key: KMutableProperty1<CellData, String>, value: String) {
    val cellData = this.tableData[index]
    key.set(cellData, value)
}

setDataValue(0, CellData::name, "arlomedia")
```

But I can't find a way to allow multiple types, like this:

```
fun setDataValue(index: TableIndex, key: KMutableProperty1<CellData, Any?>, value: Any?) {
    val cellData = this.tableData[index]
    key.set(cellData, value)
}

setDataValue(0, CellData::name, "arlomedia")
setDataValue(0, CellData::status, null)
setDataValue(0, CellData::active, true)
```

In that case, the first function call shows the error, `Type mismatch. Required: KMutableProperty1<CellData, Any?>, Found: KMutableProperty1<CellData, String>`. I didn't expect that because `Any?` is a less specific type than `String`, so I figured I could supply a `String` when all that is required is `Any?`.

I also tried:

```
fun setDataValue(index: TableIndex, key: KMutableProperty1<CellData, *>, value: Any?) {
    val cellData = this.tableData[index]
    key.set(cellData, value)
}

setDataValue(0, CellData::name, "arlomedia")
```

In that case, the error on the function call goes away, but an error appears on the `key.set` line: `Type mismatch. Required: Nothing, Found: Any?`.

I suppose I could make a separate function for each data type and call the various functions as needed, but the purpose of this function is to abstract some more complex data access, and the benefit would be lost somewhat if I had to repeat that across multiple functions.

Is there a way to do this? I've been through the [Kotlin Reflection documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html) several times, plus [this document](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/member-references-and-reflection.html) (which for some reason I've only found in the "Migrating from Python" section), and many StackOverflow answers, but I haven't found anything that ties all the necessary pieces together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using generics

```
fun <T> setDataValue(index: TableIndex, key: KMutableProperty1<CellData, T>, value: T) {
    val cellData = this.tableData[index]
    key.set(cellData, value)
}
```

Comment: It works! Here's more info: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html. If I understand this correctly, this function signature would allow me to specify a type when calling it if needed, like `setDataValue<String>(0, CellData::name, "arlomedia")`. But in my case the `<String>` isn't needed because that's evident from the `CellData::name` property.